# Svn Merge not taking Roo generated aspectj files into account

Tags: java, spring, svn, aspectj, spring-roo

I have a project with spring roo which I use to generate the javabean, jpa and service aspects for my java files. I use svn with eclipse. When I modify a javabean for example, the aj files are updated properly and I can even commit the new changed .aj files to svn without any problem. The problem starts when I try to merge these changes to a different branch of the same project. I can see the changed java files merged properly but the roo generated files do not show up in the merge. The target  branch retains the old version of these files. 
I checked in the svn history of the branch where i commited the new .aj files and they show up in the history properly.
I am really stuck and don't have a solution as of now.

Aby

Comment: Just to add - I can see the files in the preview of the merge, but when I merge, I do not see them.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse could be filtering the aj files.  you can turn off the filtering by:

- in package explorer, click down arrow on top right corner
- click filters...
- uncheck "Hide generated Spring Roo ITDs"